# ERROR: too few arguments in sorting void?

Tags: c, function, sorting, pointers, void

I'm working on this program that receives a table and then sorts it in 5 different ways (bubble sort, quicksort, insertion sort, selection sort, fusion sort) but it gives me the error above when my function needs two arguments that I have already fed it.

```
#include<stdlib.h>

//fonction affichage//
void affichage( int *t,int n) 
{
   int i,j;
   for(i=0;i<n;i++){
      printf("%d",t[i]);
      printf("\n");
   }
}

//*fonction de tri//
void Trier_Selection(int* T, int n)
{          
   int c, d, pos, temp;
   c ==0;

   for ( c = 0 ; c < ( n - 1 ) ; c++ )
   {
       pos = c;

       for ( d = c + 1 ; d < n ; d++ )
       {
          if ( T[pos] > T[d] )
             pos = d;
       }

       if ( pos != c )
       {
          temp = T[c];
          T[c] = T[pos];
          T[pos]=temp;
       }
    }

    for(c=0;c<n;c++){
        printf("%d",T[c]);
        printf("\n");
    }
 }

 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>
 main()
 {  
    int n,i,nb;
    int * t=malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    printf(" Donner la taille de votre tableau : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    //remplissage//
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
       printf(" valeur de la case T[%d]:\n ",i);
       scanf("%d",&t[i]);}

       //affichage de tableau sans tri//
       printf("votre tableau initial :\n ,%d",affichage( int *t,int n);
       //switch case//
       // le menu//
       while (nb!= 0){
          printf("********************** Le Menu **********************")
          printf(" pour le type de tri, choisir svp:\n");
          printf(" -pour Le tri par sélection tapper 1:\n");
          printf(" -pour Le tri par insertion tapper 2:\n ");
          printf(" -pour Le tri à bulle, tapper 3:\n");
          printf(" -pour Le tri rapide,taper 4:\n ");
          printf(" -pour Le tri par fusion,tapper 5:\n");
          printf(" -pour quitter, tapper 0:\n");
          scanf("%d",&nb);
       }

       switch(nb){      
          case '1'
             Tri_select(int*t,int n);
             break;
         case '2'
             tri_insert(int*t,int n);
             break;
         case'3'
             tri_bubble(int*t,int n);
             break;
         case'4'
             tri_rap(int*t,int n);
             break;
         case'5'
             tri_fusion(int*t,int n);
             break ;

         default :
            printf(" Invalid request! Try again.\n");
      }         
   }
}
```

Comment: Fix formatting. It is unreadable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: 1) `int * t=malloc(n*sizeof(int));` move to after `scanf("%d",&n);`.

Comment: 2) `case '1'
         Tri_select(int*t,int n);` --> `case 1 :
         Tri_select(t, n);`

Comment: 3) `int n,i,nb;` --> `int n,i,nb = !0;`

Comment: Usually the `#include`s are at the top of the file... in this case they *must* be.

Comment: it's just a draft, I'm still gonna redo the whole thing.

Comment: @MD XF If you don't want to help me with the original question, then go answer another 'crap'.

Comment: @SherryItaou I don't typically answer 'crap', I answer questions that deserve to be in existence.

Comment: This code is nowhere close to compiling - you don't even declare `main` properly (it should be `int main()`)

Comment: What's the actual error message?

Comment: I ctrl +c'ed and then cut some blocks , so the whole structure is off, but can you please just tell me why does it give the error? Thank you!

Comment: @melpomene "too few arguments to function 'affichage' "

Comment: @SherryItaou No, the complete actual error message (including filename and line number).

Comment: @melpomene C:\Users\user\Desktop\Hobi\Untitledmini project.c In function 'main':
53 56 C:\Users\user\Desktop\Hobi\Untitledmini project.c [Error] expected expression before 'int'
53 56 C:\Users\user\Desktop\Hobi\Untitledmini project.c [Error] too few arguments to function 'affichage'

Comment: 4) `printf("votre tableau initial :\n ,%d",affichage( int *t,int n);` , (a) Need `)` at last (before `;`). (b) return type of  `affichage` is `void`. (c) function call like `affichage(t, n)`

Comment: @SherryItaou So the actual error is `expected expression before 'int'`, not `too few arguments` or `sorting void`. The reason you're getting this error is because that's not how you call functions in C. See BLUEPIXY's comments.

Comment: Ah yes, I just did. Thank you so much . A stupid mistake ,really. Thank you again !

Answer (score 0):

Some corrections are necessary to get your program to work:

Here is a version which is working for Trier_Select --> case 1 for the switch

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

//fonction affichage//
void affichage(int *t, int n)
{
    int i;
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        printf("%d", t[i]);
        printf(" ");
    }
}

//*fonction de tri//
void Trier_Select(int* T, int n)
{
    int c, d, pos, temp;

    c = 0;

    for (c = 0; c < (n - 1); c++)
    {
        pos = c;

        for (d = c + 1; d < n; d++)
        {
            if (T[pos] > T[d])
                pos = d;
        }

        if (pos != c)
        {
            temp = T[c];
            T[c] = T[pos];
            T[pos] = temp;
        }
    }


    printf("\nResultat du tri: ");
    for (c = 0; c<n; c++) {
        printf("%d", T[c]);
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n");
}


void tri_insert(int* t, int n) {
    /* Add your code here for tri_insert*/
}

void tri_bubble(int* t, int n) {
    /* Add your code here for tri_bubble*/
}

void tri_rap(int* t, int n) {
    /* Add your code here for tri_rap*/
}

void tri_fusion(int* t, int n) {
    /* Add your code here for tri_fusion*/
}

int main(void)
{
    int n, i, nb=-1;

    printf(" Donner la taille de votre tableau : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int * t = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));


    //remplissage//
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        printf(" valeur de la case T[%d]: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &t[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    //affichage de tableau sans tri//
    printf("votre tableau initial :\n"); 
    affichage(t, n);
    //switch case//
    // le menu//
    while (nb != 0) {
        printf("\n");
        printf("********************** Le Menu **********************");
        printf(" pour le type de tri, choisir svp:\n");
        printf(" -pour Le tri par sélection tapper 1:\n");
        printf(" -pour Le tri par insertion tapper 2:\n ");
        printf(" -pour Le tri à bulle, tapper 3:\n");
        printf(" -pour Le tri rapide,taper 4:\n ");
        printf(" -pour Le tri par fusion,tapper 5:\n");
        printf(" -pour quitter, tapper 0:\n");
        printf("votre choix: ");
        scanf("%d", &nb);

        switch (nb) {
            case 1:
                Trier_Select(t, n);
                break;

            case 2:
                tri_insert(t, n);
                break;
            case 3:
                tri_bubble(t, n);
                break;
            case 4:
                tri_rap(t, n);
                break;
            case 5:
                tri_fusion(t, n);
                break;

            default:
                printf(" Invalid request! Try again.\n");
        }
    }
}
```

result:

[image]

Now you have just to add the remaining sorting methods to get the complete result: